# jackson xml lists deserialization recognized as duplicate keys

Tags: java, json, xml, list, jackson

I'm trying to convert xml into json using `jackson-2.5.1` and `jackson-dataformat-xml-2.5.1`
The xml structure is received from web server and unknown, therefore I can't have java class to represent the object, and I'm trying to convert directly into `TreeNode` using `ObjectMapper.readTree`.
My problem is jackson failing to parse lists. It is takes only the last item of the list.
code:

```
String xml = "<root><name>john</name><list><item>val1</item>val2<item>val3</item></list></root>";
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
JsonNode jsonResult = xmlMapper.readTree(xml);
```

The json result:

```
{"name":"john","list":{"item":"val3"}}
```

If I enable failure on duplicate keys `xmlMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY)`, exception is thrown:
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Duplicate field 'item' for ObjectNode: not allowed when FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY enabled`

Is there any feature which fixes this problem? Is there a way for me to write custom deserializer which in event of duplicate keys turn them into array?

Comment: you're probably out of luck https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/187#issuecomment-186986147

Comment: Seems that they it is supported now: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/issues/187#issuecomment-865132191

Answer (score 1):

I use this approach:

1. Plugin a [serializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/UntypedObjectDeserializer.html) into [XmlMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/XmlMapper.html) using a [guava multimap](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). This puts everything into lists.
2. Write out the json using [SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html). This unwrapps all lists with `size==1`.

Here is my code:

```
    @Test
    public void xmlToJson() {
        String xml = "<root><name>john</name><list><item>val1</item>val2<item>val3</item></list></root>";
        Map<String, Object> jsonResult = readXmlToMap(xml);
        String jsonString = toString(jsonResult);
        System.out.println(jsonString);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> readXmlToMap(String xml) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
            xmlMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(Object.class, new UntypedObjectDeserializer() {
                @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
                @Override
                protected Map<String, Object> mapObject(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                    JsonToken t = jp.getCurrentToken();

                    Multimap<String, Object> result = ArrayListMultimap.create();
                    if (t == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
                        t = jp.nextToken();
                    }
                    if (t == JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
                        return (Map) result.asMap();
                    }
                    do {
                        String fieldName = jp.getCurrentName();
                        jp.nextToken();
                        result.put(fieldName, deserialize(jp, ctxt));
                    } while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT);

                    return (Map) result.asMap();
                }
            }));
            return (Map) xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Object.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    static public String toString(Object obj) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true)
                    .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED, true);
            StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
            jsonMapper.writeValue(w, obj);
            return w.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

It prints

```
{
  "list" : {
    "item" : [ "val1", "val3" ]
  },
  "name" : "john"
}
```

Altogether it is a variante of this approach, which comes out without guava multimap:
https://github.com/DinoChiesa/deserialize-xml-arrays-jackson

Same approach is used here:
[Jackson: XML to Map with List deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961843/jackson-xml-to-map-with-list-deserialization)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and decided to roll my own using straightforward DOM.  The main problem is that XML does not really lends itself to a Map-List-Object type mapping like JSon does.  However, with some assumptions, it is still possible:

1. Text are stored in null keys either as a single String or a List.
2. Empty elements, i.e.  are modeled with an empty map.

Here's the class in the hope that it might just help someone else:

```
public class DeXML {

    public DeXML() {}

    public Map<String, Object> toMap(InputStream is) {
        return toMap(new InputSource(is));
    }

    public Map<String, Object> toMap(String xml) {
        return toMap(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
    }

    private Map<String, Object> toMap(InputSource input) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(input);
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
            return visitChildNode(root);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    // Check if node type is TEXT or CDATA and contains actual text (i.e. ignore
    // white space).
    private boolean isText(Node node) {
        return ((node.getNodeType() == Element.TEXT_NODE || node.getNodeType() == Element.CDATA_SECTION_NODE)
                && node.getNodeValue() != null && !node.getNodeValue().trim().isEmpty());
    }

    private Map<String, Object> visitChildNode(Node node) {    
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        // Add the plain attributes to the map - fortunately, no duplicate attributes are allowed.
        if (node.hasAttributes()) {
            NamedNodeMap nodeMap = node.getAttributes();
            for (int j = 0; j < nodeMap.getLength(); j++) {
                Node attribute = nodeMap.item(j);
                map.put(attribute.getNodeName(), attribute.getNodeValue());
            }
        }

        NodeList nodeList = node.getChildNodes();

        // Any text children to add to the map?
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {
            Node child = node.getChildNodes().item(i);
            if (isText(child)) {
                list.add(child.getNodeValue());
            }
        }
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            if (list.size() > 1) {
                map.put(null, list);
            } else {
                map.put(null, list.get(0));
            }
        }

        // Process the element children.
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); i++) {

            // Ignore anything but element nodes.
            Node child = nodeList.item(i);
            if (child.getNodeType() != Element.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                continue;
            }

            // Get the subtree.
            Map<String, Object> childsMap = visitChildNode(child);

            // Now, check if this is key already exists in the map. If it does
            // and is not a List yet (if it is already a List, simply add the
            // new structure to it), create a new List, add it to the map and
            // put both elements in it. 
            if (map.containsKey(child.getNodeName())) {
                Object value = map.get(child.getNodeName());
                List<Object> multiple = null;
                if (value instanceof List) {
                    multiple = (List<Object>)value;
                } else {
                    map.put(child.getNodeName(), multiple = new ArrayList<>());
                    multiple.add(value);
                }
                multiple.add(childsMap);
            } else {
                map.put(child.getNodeName(), childsMap);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can catch that exception and do something like :

```
List<MyClass> myObjects = mapper.readValue(input, new TypeReference<List<MyClass>>(){});
```

(got it from here [How to use Jackson to deserialise an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects))

It's a hackish approach and you will have to figure out how to resume from there.

Comment: This isn't my use case. first of all I don't have a java class. second thing, the list is embedded somewhere inside the xml, it is not list of objects under the root.

Answer (score -1):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library supports this XML.

```
String xml = "<root><name>john</name><list><item>val1</item>val2<item>val3</item></list></root>";
String json = U.xmlToJson(xml);
System.out.println(json);
```

Output JSON:

```
{
  "root": {
    "name": "john",
    "list": {
      "item": [
        "val1",
        {
          "#item": {
            "#text": "val2"
          }
        },
        "val3"
      ]
    }
  },
  "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
}
```